# How can I implement a keyboard inside my App with french characters

Tags: android

I am developing a French Verb Conjugator app and I need to implement a special keyboard which replaces usual "drag down" operations on keys with common accents and more accents for the letter if it is held down. I don't need **any** of the other chars on a keyboard, the app only deals with letters (not even numbers).

However I don't know how to go about accomplishing that... It's pretty important to the App that the user has access to the special characters and I can't *really* do much without them.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can set up a keyboard for use internally?

P.S. I looked around and didn't find any questions that answered what I am looking for, sorry if I missed any!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don"t want to do your own input method but only a keyboard for yourapp only, here you have a tutorial (in italian unfortunately) [link] http://www.anddev.it/index.php/topic,3956.0.html
and the project on gitHub here [link] https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example
I think this is exactly what you'r looking for :)

Comment: thanks I will have a read, I speak a little italian anyway haha

Comment: thanks a lot, it was exactly what I needed! Just got to make the actually keyboard now :D

Answer (score 1):

I have not done it before but if you would like to create a custom input method such as a keyboard Android has some documentation here.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: rated up, but unfortunatly I think that this is about making system wide keyboards, where as I need something isolated to my app which is also used automatically when the user has to use an edit text, instead of the user having to enable it then select it before using the app